# getting content-type="text/plain" for image?

Tags: curl, metadata, content-type, response-headers

I'm gathering the favicon of http://www.qualtrics.com/favicon.ico ,Its basically a image but the content type is `text/plain; charset=utf-8`?
can we set `text/plain; charset=utf-8` this content type for image also or image only? but in other favicons from other websites i'm getting `image/icon` as content type !

Comment: For me its `Content-Type: image/x-icon`

Comment: for me its `text/plain` only @AlexK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This server is not configured with favicon's MIME type but the browser can understand if you get CURL this URL you need to check `text/plain` also as content type.

`text/plain` is used for just simple texts. not for `html`.

`charset=utf-8` A character in UTF8 can be from 1 to 4 bytes long. UTF-8 can represent any character in the Unicode standard. UTF-8 is backwards compatible with ASCII. UTF-8 is the preferred encoding for e-mail and web pages

Answer (score 0):

The server is not configured properly with regard to the favicon's MIME-type. Browsers will accept it because the contents are valid as an icon file, but it should not have that type.

The correct type is `image/x-icon`, and you should ensure that your own server sends that header correctly.

Comment: basically where we should use `text/plain`?